# Delphi - read a Hex value in a text file and put it in a LongWord

Tags: delphi, hex, readfile

i need a little help with my project. I have a text file called Script.txt, inside of it,i have:

```
0000FCA2:FA2C
0000BC8D:F21C
```

I need to put '$0000FCA2' in a LongWord called "Address". And put '$FA2C' in a LongWord called "HexValue". And, in second line i have to do the same. '$0000BC8D' in another LongWord called "Address2" and like the first, ihave to put '$F21C' in "HexValue2" LongWord. How can i do it?

Sorry, but i'm begun with Delphi last week, so i have so many doubts. I googled for my question but don't find a good answer for it. And sorry for the wrong sentences, english isn't my first language.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: You can use `StrToInt` function for Hex number notation like `StrToInt('$ABCDEF12')`. So just add `$` char to your string and convert it by `StrToInt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own lass reading and parsing the file:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

Type
  TDataLine = class
  private
    FHexValue: LongWord;
    FAddress2: LongWord;
  public
    constructor Create(const aLine: String);
    property HexValue: LongWord read FHexValue;
    property Address2: LongWord read FAddress2;
  end;

  TDataFile = class(TObjectList<TDataLine>)
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    procedure LoadFromFile(const aFlieName: String);
  end;

  { TDataLine }

constructor TDataLine.Create(const aLine: String);
var
  Buffer: TArray<string>;
  Tmp: Int64;
begin
  Buffer := aLine.Split([':'], TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty);
  if TryStrToInt64('$' + Buffer[0], Tmp) then
    FHexValue := Tmp;

  if TryStrToInt64('$' + Buffer[1], Tmp) then
    FAddress2 := Tmp;
end;

{ TDataFile }

constructor TDataFile.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
end;

procedure TDataFile.LoadFromFile(const aFlieName: String);
var
  DataLine: TDataLine;
  Buffer: TStringlist;
  sLine: String;
begin
  Buffer := TStringlist.Create;
  try
    Buffer.LoadFromFile(aFlieName);
    for sLine in Buffer do
      Add(TDataLine.Create(sLine));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Buffer);
  end;    
end;
```

Then call it like this:

```
procedure TForm19.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  DataFile: TDataFile;
begin
  DataFile := TDataFile.Create;
  DataFile.LoadFromFile('Data.txt');
  Caption := DataFile.Count.ToString;
  DataFile.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Jens, but how i get the string for 2 lines or more? I have to put the number of line on somewhere in the code? And This function return in a String or another type of variable? Thank you so much

Comment: Hmm.. So you want the record to contain linenumber aswell? If you want more than two lines just add them to the textfle

Comment: @VictorMelo Do you need line numbers?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example for educational purposes:

```
type
  TAddress = record
    Address : LongWord;
    Value : LongWord;
 end;
 TVarAddress = array of TAddress;

var  Address : TVarAddress;


procedure GetAdressesFromTextFileIntoDynArray(FileName : String; var Arr : TVarAddress);
var
  F : TextFile;
  s, sAddr,sVal: string;
  len,p : integer;
begin
  Assign(F,FileName);
  try
    SetLength(Arr,0); //clear the array
    Reset(F);  //open text file
    len := 0;
    while not Eof(F) do
      begin
        Readln(F,s);              //read line from text file
        p := Pos(':',s);          // get position of ":"
        sAddr := Copy(s,1,p - 1); //get address from string
        sVal := Copy(s,p+1,Length(s) - p); //get value from string
        inc(len);
        SetLength(Arr,len);       //increment length of array
        Arr[len -1].Address := StrToInt('$' + sAddr);
        Arr[len -1].Value := StrToInt('$' + sVal);
      end;
  finally
    CloseFile(F);
  end;
end;
```

Use the procedure for example  :

```
GetAdressesFromTextFileIntoDynArray('c:\TextFile.txt', Address);
  for I := 0 to Length(Address) - 1 do
   begin
     Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Address[i].Address));
     Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Address[i].Value));
   end;
```

Comment: Valentine, Delphi are alerting some error on TAddress = record

"Expected an identifier but found ="

Comment: There isn't much education about showing him a oldfashion way, which should have been removed from the language lang time ago.

Comment: @VictorMelo it might work but it's not the propper way to do things. Besides that it's rude to ignore people trying to help you

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Please do not call simplest and efficient way as "oldfashion way". Modernfashion way is using web-services for such tasks :o) This answer provides simple and convenient way to solve target task without ambiguous using of generics and so on.

Comment: @Abelisto "assign" was replaced with "AssignFile" with the introduction of Delphi 3. The easiest way to read a TextFile is using a TStringList. Regarding classes and inheritance I belive it here to stay.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt It is not the easiest way to read text file of 1, 2 or 4 GB size (log files for example). Lets stop those discussion. Ask question and I answer :o)